# how do i get c# code to print position and rotation values from inspector to console?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

i am a beginner at unity and C# and struggling to get the position nad rotation valuse form the inspector to the console
i am a beginner at unity and C# and struggling to get the position nad rotation valuse form the inspector to the console

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class positions : MonoBehaviour
{
    float rx;
    float ry;
    float rz;
    float tx;
    float ty;
    float tz;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
           Debug.Log(rx);
           Debug.Log(ry);
           Debug.Log(rz);
           Debug.Log(tx);
           Debug.Log(ty);
           Debug.Log(tz);
        
        print(rx);



    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rx = GetComponent<Transform>().rotation.x; 
        ry = transform.localEulerAngles.y;
        rz = transform.localEulerAngles.z;

        tx = transform.position.x;
        ty = transform.position.y;
        tz = transform.position.z;

    }
}
```

Comment: Debug.Log() does print to the console?

Comment: Just for information `print()` is basically just a Unity method that calls `Debug.Log()` and both should print into the console as long as you didn't disable logging via.   `Debug.logger.logEnabled = false;`. Make sure you open the actual Unity console window which should be in a separate tab next to the file inspector if you use the default layout. Alternatively you can just open the Window tab on the top most bar and open General --> Console.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the inspector's rotations using `TransformUtils.GetInspectorRotation` and using `transform.position` to get the position as `Vector3`

```cs
Vector3 rv;
Vector3 p;

void Update()
{
    rv = UnityEditor.TransformUtils.GetInspectorRotation(transform);
    Debug.Log("Rotations: "+ rv.x +" "+rv.y+" "+rv.z);
    p  = transform.position;
    Debug.Log("Positions: "+ p.x +" "+p.y+" "+p.z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean update the console every frame?

If that is the case, then you would need to do this in the Update() method.

The Start() method is only called once, just before the first frame is updated.

The Update() method is called once per frame.

You can see this in the auto comment above each method in your code.

```
void Update()
{
    rx = GetComponent<Transform>().rotation.x; 
    ry = transform.localEulerAngles.y;
    rz = transform.localEulerAngles.z;

    tx = transform.position.x;
    ty = transform.position.y;
    tz = transform.position.z;

    Debug.Log(rx);
    Debug.Log(ry);
    Debug.Log(rz);
    Debug.Log(tx);
    Debug.Log(ty);
    Debug.Log(tz);
}
```

The above code would print the values to the console once for every frame.

An example can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

You can also see in the bottom left hand corner that the most recent print statement is displayed.

Hope this helps.